# Android Studio Widget faster update

Tags: android-studio, android-widget

Is there any way to update it faster than 30 min? I am trying to get a String from a website (which my code already can) and show it on a widget as an image.Code:

```java
               final RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.status_widget);

// Instantiate the RequestQueue.
       RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
        String url ="http://stats.bytewerk.org/status.txt";
// Request a string response from the provided URL.
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    public void onResponse(String response) {

                        if (response.equals("open")) {
                            views.setImageViewResource(R.id.status_nointernet, R.id.status_online);
                        } else {
                            views.setImageViewResource(R.id.status_nointernet, R.id.status_offline);
                        }
                        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);

                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                views.setImageViewResource(R.id.status_nointernet, R.id.status_nointernet);
                appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);

            }
        });
        queue.add(stringRequest);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```java
            Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Handler handler = new Handler();
                    statusUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetId); //volley request 
                    handler.postDelayed(this, 5000);
                }
            };
            runnable.run();
```